# How can I make browsers cache html files?

Tags: apache, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, browser-cache, cache-control

I want browsers to cache html files. I set up Apache2.4 and confirm css, js, png are cached, but html files are never cached.

Chrome 90 and Edge 90
Apache 2.4

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to add ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds". Hope it works !